# Is there a way to partially declare a module in a definition file?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, typescript-definitions

I'm progressively building a definition file for a library with many exports. I'd like any exports in which I don't provide any definitions for to be typed as `any`.

I know the TypeScript docs recommend adding this line to type ALL exports as `any`:

```
declare module 'some-module';
```

However, I'm not sure how to type some of the exports from the library while anything else is just a big set of `any`s.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Would this work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBAiAzsxIAtCuplvAN4CwAUPPfGMgHY4Au8AZswFzwAUveOxgBLZgHMAlPAC8APnjM0iAEYgYAblq0G8NgE8ADggCiADyPIYbHHMq69Dbn0MnknLs210GAX3gAMgdfJ3gAbQBrEAM+AAUYZBMbAwBpGIBdPihmAx89Px1QxhZ2eBBLa1s+CysbHB9Hegq6jlBOKAwOFqqGor0em0oveD8fPyA)